# Bluetooth vs BLE and proper usage of them

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am doing a project that uses BLE(CoreBluetooth).
In the mean time we use a mock in the form of android device.
My question is this:
Why does the CoreBluetooth doesn't recognise the android device? (i read about BLE GATT but still didn't understand it).
Also if i go in the iPhone to settings->bluetooth it recognises it and even connect to the android device ,how can i implement this in my app?

Comment: Your Android device will need to advertise a BLE GATT service in order to be discoverable by Core Bluetooth. iOS Settings can see legacy Bluetooth devices but these are not visible to Core Bluetooth

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the quick  response.
If i would like to do so with the classic bluetooth?
is that possible?

Comment: No,  only if your peripheral is MFi certified

Comment: @Paulw11can you elaborate on the MFI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Programming with CoreBluetooth

IMHO, CoreBluetooth is quite cumbersome. I suggest using a library like [RxBluetoothKit](https://github.com/Polidea/RxBluetoothKit) which takes away a lot of the boilerplating involved with handling the GATT profiles yourself.

### Devices, mockups

Cool BLE devices are around 30$ nowadays. I use [PuckJS](https://www.puck-js.com/) - a JS supporting programmable BLE board.

Apple requires [MFI certification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MFi_Program) for devices that connect to iOS devices via Bluetooth.

The exceptions are:

- BLE devices.
- Bluetooth devices which exclusively support [either of these profiles](https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT204387).

So your Android mockup would have to advertise itself as one of these.

Comment: Thanks for the info!